# How to pass IP address on master ec2 instance to slave ec2 instance in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have started 2 ec2 instances using cloud formation, one is master and 1 is slave.  How can I pass the private IP address of master to slave ec2 instance.  I want it to be passed to user data of slave.

```
"UserData" : {
            "Fn::Base64":{
               "Fn::Join":[
                "",
                [
                "/usr/lib/spark-2.0.1/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://Masteripaddress:7077"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FN::getatt

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

The "slave" will not launch until the "master" IP address is available, maybe until it is complete